# Script to dump two separate mysql databases and create a third database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have two mysql databases on two separate linux machines. I would like to be able to dump certain tables (e.g. e,f,g) from database a, and other tables (e.g. x,y,z) from database b. I would then like to merge the two dumps into one database. The databases have the same schema.

I need a script to do this, because I need to do this multiple times.

In case you're wondering why this needs to be done, I have an application on the live environment, but if I want to create multiple new test instances from the live environment, the users table would be too large. If I created new test instances from the preprod environment, it'd be missing certain essential data in live.

I've looked up how to do this and I can't find anything - could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqldump command (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html).

For example, for databases `a`, `b`, and tables `e`, `f`, `g`, `x`,`y`,`z`, it would be something like this:

```
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST_A a e -t >> dump.sql
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST_A a f -t >> dump.sql
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST_A a g -t >> dump.sql
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST_B b x -t >> dump.sql
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST_B b y -t >> dump.sql

cat dump.sql | mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOST_C DATABASE_C
```

(where you should replace the vars in capital letters with your actual values)

The first lines dumps the data (without table structure, as there is the flag `-t`) to the file `dump.sql`, which is finally used to insert the rows into a different database (DATABASE_C at HOST_C).

If you want a script, just put the commands in a bash file and parametrize the vars you want.